# How do I modify char in read-only memory

Tags: c++, pointers

When I try to edit the value of a char pointer like this, I get an access violation. I know, that the compiler locates this in a read-only memory block, but is there any way to unlock this like`GlobalUnlock()` or `HeapUnlock()`

```
int main()
{
    char* foo = "Hello";
    *foo = 'B'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use lock/unlock. Keep it simple. If you intend to modify the string, use a `char` array or a `std::string`.

```
char foo[] = "Hello";
*foo = 'B'
```

or

```
std::string foo = "Hello";
foo[0] = 'B'
```